# Replace % with \% if not already replaced in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I have some text which has some `%` and some `\%`. I want to replace all occurrences of `%` with `\%`, without converting \% to `\\%`. I tried:

```
%s/\\\@!%/\\%/g
```

But it is not working.

Sample text can be:

```
This % and this % should be replaced but not these two: \% and \%.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `/(?<!\\)%/` should work, but I don't know that vim supports "negative-lookbehind" operations inside the regular expressions.

Comment: It is not working: `pattern not found: (?<!\\)%`

Comment: I know `vim` doesn't support it, but that's the expression you need. I don't know of a reasonable alternative other than a three pass thing: Replace `\%` with some other junk, replace `%` with `\%`, then replace the other junk with `\%` again. A two-pass approach just fixes the erroneous `\\%` things it generates, patching them back to single.

Comment: You could process this file with `perl` using that regular expression if you're up against the wall here.

Comment: Can I make a generic vim function for such replacements, str to be replaced with prefix-str unless already prefixed?

Comment: @tadman : What is perl command for this?

Comment: Yes `:%s/\(\\\)\@<!%/\\%/g` works. `@<` seems to be the key code.

Comment: `:s/[^\\]\zs%/\\%/g` also works. Here, what is replaced is after \zs

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt that won't work if `%` is at start of line

Comment: @Sundeep, you're absolutely right. This `:s/\(^\|[^\\]\)\zs%/\\%/g` would fix that, but it still has the problem of not taking into account escaped backslashes mentioned below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim supports negative look-behinds, like this:

```
:s/\(\\\)\@<!%/\\%/g
```

This breaks down as:

```
s/      # substitute...
  \(    #   start group 1
    \\  #     a backslash
  \)    #   end group 1
  \@<!  #   group option: negative look-behind
  %     #   a "%" sign
/       # with...
  \\%   #   "\%"
/g      # globally.
```

You could also do `:s/%/\\%/g` followed by `:s/\\\\%/\\%/g`.

Comment: ...which is the default AFAIK.

Comment: Sure, but you still don't want to contribute to the countless plugins that break if you add `set nomagic` to your vimrc.  It's much easier to add `\m` at the beginning of your pattern.  A similar reasoning holds for case sensitivity.

Comment: Right.  Still a bad habit though.

Comment: I'm not "contributing to a plugin" here anyway. I'm writing down a regular expression to do a search-and-replace operation. People who write Vim plugins should a) be aware of portability issues and b) know Vim regex well enough to not copy and use random expressions from some SO question.

Comment: No, but you're teaching people to write regexes in Vim.  `magic` is something they should be aware of.

Comment: Yes, they will learn when they fall over it for the first time, like virtually everybody else did. A quick 101 of the Vim regex basics is out of scope for such a simple question.

Answer (score 3):

We can make use of greediness of `?` here

```
:%s/\\\?%/\\%/g
```

- `\\\?` will match `\` zero or one time. As `?` is greedy, it will consume if `\` is present
- So, in effect, both `\%` and `%` will get replaced with `\%`

Comment: Likely you you want to replace \\% with \\\% because the first backslash is escaping the second one, and the percentage sign doesn't have any. But it's just a guess, since the author doesn't say anything about that. There was a regex this morning taking that into account, but it's gone now

Comment: well, OP mentions text having `%` and `\%` in description... but yeah, if `\\%` should be replaced with `\\\%`, my solution won't work...

Comment: You're right. It says nothing about that, and so far it's the simplest and therefore best solution

Answer (score -1):

From the console

echo Replace % and  % but not \% and \%. |sed -e s/%/\\\%/g

Gives
    Replace % and  % but not \% and \%.

Hope that's what you're looking for.  If so, just do the whole file with

cat FileName  |sed -e s/%/\\\%/g